# Incompatible server memory

Tags: memory, hardware

Why are these two pinouts different? They are keyed differently. See attached pictures.

[image: memory stick labels]
[image: memory stick pins]

Comment: And you don't have one up-side-down compared to the other?

Comment: Do you have one upside down?

Comment: Regardless of how they are rotated the slots do not line up.

Comment: A side note apart my answer, one of my friend used to force a ddr in a wrong slot (don't repair your computer while under alchool..), and the motherboard burned when he started the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply another type of DDR model.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM

or from http://www.ocinside.de/review/crucial_4x4gb_ddr4_2133/

> By the way, not only the number of pins, which have risen from 240-pin
>   (DDR3) to 288-pin (DDR4), but also the DDR4 module design is new,
>   because the bottom of the modules is no longer plane, but slightly
>   flattened on both sides. In addition also the (voltage) **notch is on
>   another position, to avoid that one is accidentally installing DDR4
>   modules in a DDR3 socket or DDR3 modules in a DDR4 slot.** DDR3 and DDR4
>   memory is not pin compatible.

[image]

Comment: The motherboard manual states that it accepts 667 or 800MHz fully buffered DDR2 SDRAM DIMMs. In the image, the one with heat spreaders is compatible and the other isn't. So I wonder what the other one is?

Comment: Is it the "voltage notch" that's different?

Comment: @Reinderien both product code return DDR2 memory from google, strange, but yes, they do that center different to prevent you to install it in the server.

Comment: It ended up being that the motherboard requires fully-buffered memory, and what I bought was not FB.